# How to show an error message if the user chooses the default option?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a `DropDownList` in my `View` which is filled in the controller and is passed to the `View` using `ViewBag.PussibleManager`

```
@Html.DropDownList("PussibleManager", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The first item of this ddl is "please choose..." and it's value is set to -1.

How can I check if the selected item is "please choose..." and show an error message in something like `Html.ValidationMessage` if the user pushes the save button?

(I want to force the user to select a manager or the save button doesn't work!)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery UI autocomlete modified to combobox (http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html)

P.S.: Take a look at page code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line of code to your view:

```
@Html.Validate("PussibleManager")
```

And then add something similar to the following code into the action result:

```
public ActionResult NameOfAction(NameOfViewModel model)
{
    if (model.PussibleManager = 0)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("PussibleManager", "ErrorMessageHere");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       // DO SOMETHING HERE
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

What will occur is, when the form submits (assuming it is a form) it will post to the server. It will pick up that there is an error with the DDL and then instead of carrying on when it hits the `ModelState.IsValid` it will return false, head back to the view and return an error message.

This is one of many examples, you could use DataAnnotations on a ViewModel you're passing back in. Also NameOfViewModel is just a class with items you're passing back from your view to your server.

Alternatively, you could use JQUERY Validation as per the other user's response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I said, this dropdownlist is filled in my controller and it doesn't exist in a ViewModel.

Comment: Still follow the example I gave you, but in place of `NameOfViewModel model` (refer to ActionResult) change it to `string PussibleManager`. Oh and remove `return View(model);` to just say `return View();` If you still don't like the answer, my recommendation is then to look at JQUERY Validation.